# Openfiledialog and Savefiledialog modification

Tags: c#, .net, customization, openfiledialog

Is it possible to remove the tree view from the *Open and Save file* dialog's in .NET?

Would it be possible to find the handle of the tree view and destroy the window using *Win32 API*'s?

I could not find a way in the `OpenFileDialog` class to hide the tree view. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set AutoUpgradeEnable to false.
Then you will get the old fashioned looking dialog when running on Vista or later.
That was what you meant, right?

Comment: This should be the OP's Requirement.

Comment: What I meant was I don't want the shortcuts such as pictures,documents etc. I'll try this and let you know

Comment: @Aster Veigas, if my answer is that what you were looking for, than please mark it as answer.

Comment: It still gives the shortcuts on the right. how do i get rid of that?